# Expected a real got "1,000.00"

Tags: r

I am trying to use scan() to read in a very large data set that has variables beginning on different rows. One column contains numbers, some of which are simply 20, others are 1,000.00. My code to read this data in looks like:

```
largedata<-scan(paste0(folder,df.txt),
            what=list("","","",0,"","","",""),
            skip=20,sep="\t",quote="",dec=".")
```

But my larger numbers, in the thousands, are not cooperating. I included the dec="." to try to eliminate the problem, but I am still getting this error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '1,000.00'
```

If I just make my numeric column to be character with all the others, my data set reads in fine, but when I convert to data.frame, everything turns into a factor, and when converting the factor to numeric, my numeric values of 1,000.00 and above all become NA. Is there a way that I can read in numbers that have both commas and decimals in this format? I cannot think of another way to read in my data other than using scan().

Comment: use the second method, sub out the commas, then convert to numeric

Comment: duh, how did I not think of that..